# How to pass a vector of objects to another class then call a function from within a member of an object in that vector?

Tags: c++, pointers, vector, reference, callback

How to pass a vector via a function call to a pointer to a vector in another class and call a function or element via the receiving class; and how to call that function in the receiving class remotely?

In this example, object0 is an object type containing a function that will be called.

Object0 will be created in object1 as a member of a vector.

Then that vector will be passed to object2, wherein it will be called from an external object; here arbitrarily chosen as within object1;

main() is just a way of booting this app up, and I would welcome suggestions on improving it.

```
#include <vector> 
class object0
{
protected:
    int a;
    void function()
    {
        std::cout << "function called" << std::endl;
    }
};

class object2
{
    public:
    std::vector<object0> *object0vec;
    void knowvector(std::vector<object0> *_object0vec)
    {
        object0vec = _object0vec;
    }
};

class object1
{
public:
    object2* _object2;
    object1()
    {
        _object2 = new object2;
    }
    void init()
    {
        std::vector<object0> object0vec;
        object0vec.push_back(new object0)
        _object2.object0vec[0].function();
```

How to get this line working? _object2.object0vec[0].function();

```
    }
};
int main()
{
    object1 newobject1;
    object1 &ref_newobject1 = newobject1;
    ref_newobject1.init();
}
```

Comment: You just forgot to use `knowvector` to put `object0vec` into `_object2`. However, this whole code is wrong on many levels...

Answer (score 0):

In init():

"_object2" has lifetime the same as object1.
Yet, in init() you presumably will pass a pointer to the local variable object0vec to knowvector().
So now, "_object2" has a longer lifetime than an object it has a poiner to, yet doesn't own.
"knowvector" could make a copy of the vector instead of keeping a pointer.

Syntax:

In Init(), "_object2" is a pointer, so you need to use ->.

object2::object0vec is also a pointer while presumably "object0vec[0]" is meant to get the first object in the vector, not the first in an array of vectors.

```
_object2 -> (*object0vec)[0].function();
```